# How to get the right namespace output

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, xml-serialization

I have a class that implements IXmlSerializable. When I use a custom XmlWriter/XmlReader, it just works fine and outputs the right output. However, when I use it in WCF, I get a very clean output, it's a bit too clean because it does not contain any type info:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <GetModelCResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <GetModelCResult>
                <D xmlns="">D</D>
                <E xmlns="">
                    <B>B</B>
                    <A>A</A>
                </E>
            </GetModelCResult>
        </GetModelCResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

However, I would expect something like this (which it *does* write when using a XmlWriter):

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <GetModelCResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <GetModelCResult xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Model" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <a:D>D</a:D>
                <a:E i:type="a:ModelA">
                    <a:A>A</a:A>
                    <a:B>B</a:B>
                </a:E>
            </GetModelCResult>
        </GetModelCResponse>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

What am I doing wrong? Is it a configuration issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the serializer that wcf uses.

One way you might achieve this is to decorate with the

```
[XmlSerializerFormat]
```

attribute at the top of your service implementation.

If you need a few more bells and whistles, you could consider a custom serializer.

Dan Rigsby wrote an article some time ago related to this topic at [his blog](http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/03/07/xmlserializer-vs-datacontractserializer-serialization-in-wcf/). Near the end of the article, he discuesses creating an implementation of IOperationBehavior to

The idea is simple enough, create an operation behavior that replaces the normal serializer with a custom one.  As long as that class inherits from Attribute, you can use it to decorate the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

We had something similar a while back and I noted this in my past notes:
http://www.pluralsight-training.net/community/blogs/kirillg/archive/2006/06/18/28380.aspx

See if that gives some information helpful here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I cannot see how I could use that to change the actual output.